# Ler arquivo de texto pegando números float e jogando em matriz

Tags: c, arquivo, matriz, alocação

Tenho um arquivo de texto por exemplo com:

```
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
```

A saída esperada é um matriz de float 8x3 (nesse caso), pois a matriz sempre terá o mesmo número de linhas que o arquivo, com os respectivos valores de cada linha, seja:

```
[0][1] =  1.000000
[0][2] = -1.000000
[0][3] = -1.000000

[1][1] =  1.000000
[1][2] = -1.000000
[1][3] =  1.000000
.
.
.
```

Como tem muito tempo que não mexo com C, eu acabei esquecendo um bocado de coisas e minhas tentativas não foram nem de perto o esperado, só consigo ler caracter por caracter da linha e identificar quando a quebra de linha. Alguém pode ajudar a resolver esse problema, de pegar 3 floats por linha?

Última tentativa foi para contar o número de linhas, deu ceto, mas a partir daí não achei como pegar os 3 floats da linha:

```
void readOBJ(char *file)
{
    char ch;
    int lines = 0;

    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen(file, "r");
    if(arq == NULL)
            printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    else {
        do {
            ch = fgetc(arq);
            if(ch == '\n')
                lines ++;
        }while(ch != EOF);
    }

    fclose(arq);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `fscanf` possui um sistema de formatação inteligente. Se as linhas que você precisa ler seguem esse padrão (começando com v e seguido por 3 floats), então é possível fazer algo do tipo:

```
fscanf(arq, " v %f %f %f", &v[i][0], &v[i][1], &v[i][2]);
```

Para saber quando parar (final de arquivo), use o valor de retorno de `fscanf`: a função devolve um valor positivo se conseguir ler alguma coisa, e `EOF` se tiver chegado ao fim.

Comment: Consegui aqui, obrigado.